# JavaScript module import wildcard * versus explicit import

Tags: javascript

**QUESTION**

There are a number of posts about this topic, but I'm still unsure as to the best practice for JS imports.

**STYLE GUIDES CONFLICT**

Google Style Guide [Google Import Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#es-module-imports) suggest the following approach is "good"

```
import * as goog from '../closure/goog/goog.js';
```

AirBNB Style Guide [AirBNB Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#modules--no-wildcard) clearly states not use wildcards.

**Observation**
As I look through some respected JS developers I see them use wildcards. Originally I suspected it was for namespace or aliasing purposes, but I've seen this type of example more often than not.

```
import * as debounce from 'lodash/debounce.js'
```

The only reason I can imagine is maintainability i.e. debounce will remain debounce independent of export, and in this cases debounce will debounce as long as a debounce.js file exists.

The difference between

**OPTION 1:**

```
import debounce from "lodash/debounce.js";
```

OR

**OPTION 2:**

```
import * as debounce from 'lodash/debounce.js'
```

Is that option 1 seems to generate (example only)

```
var _debounce = require('./lodash/debounce.js');
```

and option 2 adds a bit of iteration code.

```
var _debounce = require('./lodash/debounce.js');

var Debounce = _interopRequireWildcard(_debounce);

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { 
    if (obj && obj.__esModule) { 
        return obj;
    } else {
        var newObj = {}; 
        if (obj != null) { 
            for (var key in obj) { 
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key))
                    newObj[key] = obj[key];
            }
        }
        newObj.default = obj; 
        return newObj;
    }
}
```

**Best Practice?**

Is there a best practice for the average JS developer?

1. `import * as debounce from 'lodash/debounce.js' // wildcard import`
2. `import debounce from 'lodash/debounce.js' // submodule import`
3. `import {debounce} from 'lodash' // deconstruction import`
4. `import _ , { debounce, throttle } from 'lodash'; // everything but the sink`
5. `import debounce from 'lodash.debounce' // method import`

**Method vs Submodule**

As a side note there is also conflict about submodule vs. method imports i.e.

**Submodule Import**

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'
```

**Method Import**

```
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce'
```

but I read that method imports don't share code and as such the memory footprint will be slightly larger, whereas submodules do, which would be important in larger libraries.

My gut feel is wildcard imports are a code smell (like infinity in science), but I feel I might misunderstand the nuances in the style guides.

Is the takeaway here that both are right, but only use wildcards

1. for maintainability / longevity when importing 3rd party code
2. smaller libraries or utilities a more efficient approach
3. namespacing?

or ...

Comment: Whatever you choose its better to be consistant

Comment: AirBNB's "*[Do not use wildcard imports.](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#modules--no-wildcard)*" with "*Why? This makes sure you have a single default export.*" does not make any sense. They also have "*[In modules with a single export, prefer default export over named export](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#modules--prefer-default-export)*" which *does* make sense, but only because it is limited to modules with a single export. If you have multiple (named) exports, nothing should stop you from using namespace imports.

Comment: "*submodule vs. method imports*" - I've never heard of the second, and they also do not seem to be interchangeable. Do you have references for that?

Comment: @Bergi this was the post on github https://github.com/fkhadra/react-on-screen/issues/55

Comment: @Nolan Ah, that's really a lodash-specific thing. The provide completely separate package for each function - a thing that nobody else does, and that they plan on deprecating anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...but I've seen this type of example more often than not.
>
> ```
> import * as debounce from 'lodash/debounce.js'
> ```
>
> The only reason I can imagine is maintainability i.e. `debounce` will remain `debounce` independent of export, and in this cases `debounce` will `d`ebounce as long as a `debounce.js` file exists.

While that's true, it's not particularly useful, because `debounce` in that example is just an object (specifically, it's called a *module namespace object*). It's just a container. It has properties for all the named exports in `debounce.js` and if there's also a default export, a property called `default`. Those (other than `default` of course) will still change if the exports in `debounce.js` change.

> The difference between
>
> OPTION 1:
>
> ```
> import debounce from "lodash/debounce.js";
> ```
>
> OR
>
> OPTION 2:
>
> ```
> import * as debounce from 'lodash/debounce.js'
> ```

The difference is in *what they do*, not (just) the output that (say) Webpack creates for them. They do **different things**.

`import debounce from 'lodash/debounce.js'` imports the default export from `debounce.js` and binds it to a local *binding* (loosely, *variable*) called `debounce`.

`import * as debounce from 'lodash/debounce.js'` imports **ALL** of the exports from `debounce.js` wrapped up in a module namespace object and binds that object to a local binding called `debounce`.

In the first example, assuming the default export of `lodash/debounce.js` is a function, you'd use it as:

```
const newFunction = debounce(someFunction, someDelay);
```

In the second example, you'd have to use a property on the module namespace object; assuming it's the default export, that would be:

```
const newFunction = debounce.default(someFunction, someDelay);
```

Those are fundamentally different.

So the best practice is to do the thing you actually want to do. Sometimes, you want the module namespace object, though (opinion!) I suspect that's fairly rare. Generally, you probably want to import specific exports, either the default one (`import x from ...`) or a named one (`import { x } from ...`).

Comment: FWIW, I go into modules in depth in Chapter 13 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*, including the various forms of `import` and `export`. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed response. Sorry for my delay been troubleshooting Webpack, but Im pleased to say at 4AM I have it working ... lol ... thanks again